# Redirect old custom Posts URL to new WordPress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, post, redirect

In short, I converted my old custom site to a new WordPress site, the domain remains same, I used PHP to insert thousands of old articles with its comments into WordPress database maintaining the same id sequence, meaning if the old links were:

[www.mysite.com/index.php?id=11058](http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=11058)

[www.mysite.com/index.php?category=12](http://www.mysite.com/index.php?category=12)

Than the new link are:

[www.mysite.com/?p=11058](http://www.mysite.com/?p=11058)

[www.mysite.com/?cat=12](http://www.mysite.com/?cat=12)

Everything was done well, the only problem is that I don't want to lose the old backlinks, and I want to use PHP to redirect, for example:

```
    if (isset($_GET['old_id'])) {  $id=$_GET['old_id']; $Wordpress_post_id = $id; }
```

How can I use this code in WordPress? and is this method better or redirect by .htaccess? Or is there another way that is better than the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/):

> This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load. It is a good hook to use if you need to do a redirect with full knowledge of the content that has been queried.

```php
add_action(
    'template_redirect',
    static function() {

        if(!isset($_GET['old_id'])){
            return;
        }

        // Do custom look up here, possibly get_posts()

        // Once you determine where to go, use wp_safe_redirect with the appropriate code (probably 301)
        // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/

        // Also possibly use get_permalink() to find the canonical link for the object
        // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, the "custom stuff" is really dependent upon how you stored things. Is it post meta, did you manually insert post IDs, is it a custom lookup table?

If it is a true mapping of legacy IDs to PostIDs, you might even be able to use a plugin such as [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) with a simple rule.

Comment: I think it's better to use plugin than to modify the script myself since I'm new to WordPress.

Comment: I used WordPress functions  to insert posts and comments (wp_insert_post() and wp_insert_comment()). thank you very much.

Comment: If the Redirection plugin works, I say totally go for it. However, if you are comfortable in PHP, this code doesn't need a whole lot of WordPress stuff on the inside.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know much about how WordPress works and structure. Inserting posts, comments and images was easy because all I had to do was put them in an array and then use the WordPress functions to insert them in the database, but this matter, the redirection, seems more complicated. I will try PHP solution on my pc localhost, if succeed with it I will implement it on the site.
So grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned (and tagged) `.htaccess` you could do it like this at the top of the `.htaccess` file (before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker):

```
# Redirect "/index.php?id=<number>" to "/?p=<number>"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /?p=%1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect "/index.php?category=<number>" to "/?cat=<number>"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /?cat=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the preceding *CondPattern* in both cases. ie. the value of the `id` and `category` URL parameters respectively.

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Comment: I will give it a try.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do the same thing. I reorganized a site and moved the structure from the root (and all directory structure) to the **blog** folder. I experimented with several methods for WordPress, analyzed logs for issues, etc., and implemented the following method.

First I created a list of every page, article, etc.

Then I created a **.htaccess** file located in the site root directory.

In my example below I show the redirect for one page, but with two entries (trailing slash or not). The bottom portion handles files and directors, etc.

My .htaccess is about 600 lines long. I have not noticed any performance issues with the redirects.

Note: I am using a 302 for redirects, if yours are permanent, consider using a 301.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^aboutme$ https://www.example.com/blog/aboutme/ [L,R=302]
  RewriteRule ^aboutme/$ https://www.example.com/blog/aboutme/ [L,R=302]

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  # Send Requests To Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Seems a little complicated since I don't have much experience with .htaccess and I'm afraid to make a mistake.. I want a simple solution.. Thank you

Comment: @AyadAttar I do not think there is a simple solution for WordPress. You have to handle the corner cases. WordPress has many methods of displaying articles and pages as URLs. Whatever method you choose, invest the time to study the log files as there will be problems.

Comment: You are absolutely right, there is no simple solutions .. I really should make more effort to learn how WordPress works.. The problem is that managing site, editing and writing new posts doesn't leave me any time to learn new things.. That's why I try to shorten the time and effort by asking experts.. I think the problem I'm facing , as well as many website owners, is that they fail to form a team to manage their site .. You cannot do everything on your own .. Thank you very much for the advice.